# Proving $P(\bigcap A_i)\geq\sum P(A_i)-(n-1)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I need to prove $P(\bigcap A_i)\geq\sum P(A_i)-(n-1)$.

I tried playing with $\sum P(A_i)\geq P(\bigcup A_i)\geq\sum P(A_i)-\sum_{1\leq i\lt j\leq n}P(A_i\cap A_j)$, but didn't get anywhere.

A hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint:  For $n=1$ this is trivially true.  For $n=2$ use the fact that $1≥P(A\cup B)$.  Proceed by induction.

Comment: @lulu
Thanks again lulu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P((\bigcap A_{i})^{c})=P(\bigcup A_{i}^{c}) \le \sum P(A_{i}^{c})= \sum(1-P(A_{i})) $

Then follows:

$1-P(\bigcap A_{i}) \le n-\sum P(A_{i})$

which is what you want